# Using Spring Form tag for Edit Functionality

Tags: forms, spring-mvc

In my web app. I have a domain Object(bean) which i have mapped to one of my tables via hibernate, i have used the same domain object reference to a spring form tag in my "addcustomer.jsp" which is used to add customers, this way whenever a customer is added spring form tag fill's up my domain object and i can persist this to my DB. However, when i use the same technique in my "editcustomer.jsp", the domain object that i get in my controller flushes all the fields information and only gives me that information which has been changed/edited. Hence, i cannot blindly persist this entire domain object to my db as it does not have the rest of the information.

I think spring form flushes all the information from the existing bean, re-populates it with the available information and post it to the request, i am not sure how spring form tag behaves, but this is what i can guess.

If this is a real problem, then following are two possible solution i can come to
1. instead of blindly persisting the domain object to db, query the db to get the existing record and do a merge/replace - This approach leads to an extra db call before you persist the data which you had already made before going to editcustomer.jsp
2. Maintain the copy of the domain object on the request at jsp end, and return the same copy along with the spring form created bean and do the merge at the controller end. - Probably not a good idea

Is there any other way you think we can achieve this? Or using spring form tag in this scenario is not a good idea

Thanks
Vinod

Answer (score 1):

You will have to load the `customer` object to your model before you render the editcustomer.jsp. then you can use the form like this:

```
<form:form commandName="customer">
    <form:hidden path="id" />
    ...
    First Name:<form:input path="firstName" />
    Last Name:<form:input path="lastName" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
</form:form>
```

Add the values that you don't want to be editable by the user as hidden fields in the form. This way, when the controller binds the form to your object, it will have all the information needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can first check that you have bind the values to a form field of spring using path attribute, because if you have properly bind the pojo class variables to form tags using a path attribute then on form submission spring use web data binder to set the values of fields into pojo variables by using variables setter method. For more Better understanding by code refer the @Vasileios Liolios answer.